# google cloud functions release resources without respond request

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I want to release the resources associated with a node js request without sending any kind of response to the client.

This might sound weird but my goal is very simple, the last few days my servers have been targeted by hackers... i'm trying to improve the defenses and if i identify a malicious request i could just DROP IT without sending any response i would make the attacker wait for connection timeout and it would give a little more advantage.

i tried:

```
exports.test = (req, res) => {
res.end();
};
```

but this case the server sends an empty response which isn't my goal since i want make client wait forever

also tried:

```
exports.test = (req, res) => {
res.socket.destroy();
};
```

which on google cloud functions throws an exception

does anyone know if on GCF if i simple return the function it will be released or the connection will be hang on?

```
exports.test = (req, res) => {
return; //will google release all resources or connection and socket will be kept until timeout?
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions does not enable what you're trying to do.  The only way it will keep the connection open is if your function times out *with no response*.  You can't instruct it to keep the connection open while also terminating the function.  Or, to put it another way, you're going to have to pay the usual Cloud Functions rate for execution-seconds in order to keep that connection open.